# How to change input method when using command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

There are several [input methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) like Chinese, Japanese, or Russian.

But, when I change code page into 65001 (UTF-8), I can **only** type English.

How to change input method when using command prompt under code page UTF-8 ?

Any help would be appreciated.